# Why is the margin attained with $\Phi=\left[2 x, 2 x^{2}\right]^{T}$ greater than the margin attained with $\Phi=\left[x, x^{2}\right]^{T}$?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, support-vector-machine, homework, kernel-trick

I am trying to understand the solution to part 4 of problem 3 from the midterm exam [6.867 Machine learning: Mid-term exam (October 15, 2003)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-867-machine-learning-fall-2006/exams/midterm_f03soln.pdf).

For reproducibility, here is problem 3.

> We consider here linear and non-linear support vector machines (SVM) of the form:
> $$
> \begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> \min w_{1}^{2} / 2 & \text { subject to } y_{i}\left(w_{1} x_{i}+w_{0}\right)-1 \geq 0, \quad i=1, \ldots, n, \text { or } \\
> \min \mathbf{w}^{T} \mathbf{w} / 2 & \text { subject to } y_{i}\left(\mathbf{w}^{T} \Phi_{i}+w_{0}\right)-1 \geq 0, \quad i=1, \ldots, n
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}
> $$
> where $\Phi_{i}$ is a feature vector constructed from the corresponding real-valued input $x_{i}$. We wish to compare the simple linear SVM classifier $\left(w_{1} x+w_{0}\right)$ and the non-linear classifier
> $\left(\mathbf{w}^{T} \Phi+w_{0}\right)$, where $\Phi=\left[x, x^{2}\right]^{T}$.

Here is part 4 of the same problem.

> In general, is the margin we would attain using scaled feature vectors
> $\Phi=\left[2 x, 2 x^{2}\right]^{T}$
>
> - greater
> - equal
> - smaller
> - any of the above

The correct answer is the first (**greater**). Why is that the case?

Comment: Because the 2nd kernel is scaled by 3. So k margin in 1st will have 3k margin in 2nd.

Comment: @DuttaA would you clarify a bit more? I didn't get the point.

Comment: Say you have a classifier wx+b=0. The margin of a datapoint is defined as wx_i+b. Clearly dependent on magnitudes of w, x_i and b. Here your data is 3 times the original data. This is a common paradigm in SVMs, so I would suggest you to read about SVMs.